# What happened to the other symbiotes in Venom?

Tags: plot-explanation, venom

After Drake died with Riot in *Venom*, the symbiotes were still in Drake's lab. So what happened to them? Are they disposed or sent back to space?

Comment: They will use them in sequel?

Comment: Didn't they all die at some point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the beginning of the movie, there are a total of four symbiotes. One escaped in the crash and hopped from one host to another. The other three were taken to the lab.

It is explained earlier in the movie in a one-off sentence that symbiotes need a host to live in an oxygen rich environment. The symbiotes also killed their hosts if they weren't compatible matches, so Carlton Drake's solution was to just keep sending in "volunteers" in hopes that one of them becomes a stable match.

Eddie Brock escaped the lab while bonded with a symbiote. Drake evidently ran out of hosts as there are two quick scenes that show dead symbiotes. Drake also explains to Riot that he tried his best to keep them alive.

TLDR:

There are four symbiotes total on Earth. Riot continually bonded with hosts until he found Drake. Venom bonded with Eddie. The other two unnamed ones are dead because they were unable to find a suitable host.

Comment: We see one dead symbiote (yellow I think?) in the pictures Eddie takes of the lab, and we see the other (blue?) dead after it's set on Jenny Slate's character. Drake yells at his subordinates about that one.

Comment: The Yellow one, Scream, was accepted by the rabbit and you don't see it again throughout the movie, so it could still be alive and hopping around somewhere!

Comment: @Tfish I distinctly remember two scenes that showed dead symbiotes. They tried to bond it with a human.

Comment: @deeV Okay my bad, turns out it was  Phage anyway hahah "Although Riot escaped, a number of symbiote samples were still obtained by the Life Foundation." https://screenrant.com/venom-movie-villains-symbiotes/  I cant seem to add spoiler tags, not sure why but sorry!

Answer (score 3):

I believe we see that the two other symbiotes are dead, either because they couldn't find a suitable host or the host died. One dead one is seen when they are talking about running out of test subjects and other one is seen dead when the doctor killed herself.

Comment: The doctor didn't kill herself.

Answer (score 1):

Warnning Spoiler!!

> Carnage's Host is shown in the post credit scene, teasing a second venom Movie.
>  Thus meaning the Red symbiot survived.

Comment: That may be the direction they are going. Though Carnage in the comics is the son (or spawn) of Venom. It depends on the direction they choose for the movie.